# How to build .net core application in Jenkins using docker and push it to ECR?

Tags: docker, jenkins, .net-core, amazon-ecs

Hi I am learning to build pipeline using Jenkins and AWS for my .net core application. I created sample application at `https://github.com/niranjan2020/JenkinsPipeLine`
I downloaded Jenkins in my local and running at port 8080. I created Pipeline template for creating Jenkins pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }

    stages {
        stage('checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage('First Stage') {
            steps {
                echo "Yay! First stage is executed"
            }
        }
stage('Build') {
           agent {
              docker {
          image 'microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk'
          args '-u root:root'
        }
      }

      steps {
        sh 'apt update'
        sh 'apt install -y apt-transport-https'

        // sh 'echo "{\\\"buildNumber\\\":\\\"${BUILD_NUMBER}\\\", \\\"sha\\\":\\\"need to populate\\\"}" > Jenkins/buildinfo.json'
        sh 'echo Hi'
        sh 'chmod a+rw -R .'
        stash name: 'Jenkins-out', includes: 'Jenkins/out/**'
      }
    }
}
}
```

I want to build my .net core application using docker and put the image to ECR. Using above code I am able to execute first stage but I am not able to execute second stage.

```
process apparently never started in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ECS@2@tmp\durable-8251f4a8
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
```

This error message I am getting. In the above repository I have not added the docker file. Do I need to add it? Can someone help me to figure it out this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are want to push image on ECR, then you should put every dependency in your dockerfile, like in Jenkins you can run postscript which install depencey for you in containers but that is not the case in AWS ECR. Your Docker iamge should able to run without any post script.

your Dockerfile will look like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output
# Runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/output .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNetProject.dll"]
```

the `build-env` will build your app at the first stage, and the second will copy the build app from the build stage.

If you Jenkins server inside AWS VPC, assign the [role](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/new-attach-an-iam-role-to-your-existing-amazon-ec2-instance/) to Jenkins server which has access to ECR.

if running outside then feed the [credential](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2016/04/pushing-to-ecr-using-jenkins-pipeline-plugin/).

[image]

```
node {
  stage 'Checkout'
  git 'ssh://https://github.com/niranjan2020/JenkinsPipeLine'

  stage 'Docker build'
  docker.build('demo')

  stage 'Docker push'
  docker.withRegistry('https://1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:us-east-1:demo-ecr-credentials') {
    docker.image('demo').push('latest')
  }
}
```

update registry URL with your ECR.

you can check further [here](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2016/04/pushing-to-ecr-using-jenkins-pipeline-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adiii. So Do I need to change my docker file as above(you posted one in answer) along with above jenkins file?

Comment: yes off course you need to change to your Dockerfile, ECR expects everything docker image, you can run postscript but I will not recommend that.

Comment: I am facing issue with connecting using  git 'ssh://https://github.com/niranjan2020/JenkinsPipeLine'. Already i configured Git in Configure. Is this step required here? Next  docker.build('demo')
where docker execute builds? In my local system?

Comment: Also during docker build I am getting error process apparently never started in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ECS@tmp\durable-305ac4cd
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer). May I know what would be the issue

Comment: Whats issue with git? try to https instead of ssh

Comment: I am using https now. Also docker.build(JenkinsPipeLine/Jenkins/Jenkins/) path should be where dockerfile is present right?

Comment: it should be an absolute or relative path, the path Dockerfile but better to relative if there is context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200061/discussion-between-niranjan-and-adiii).